# why getElementById dosn't work with <script>... tag but work with php echo '<script>

Tags: php, jquery, select, echo

i have an select option on my page & to load `syslogout.php` according to selected option i wrote this code :

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#divSys").mouseup(function() { 
 var open = $(this).data("isopen");
 if(open) { 
   window.location="sysLogout.php?sysid="+document.getElementById("divSys").value; 
 }
 $(this).data("isopen", !open); });
</script>';
```

it's work fine. but this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">$("#divSys").mouseup(function()  {
   var open = $(this).data("isopen"); 
   if(open) { 
      window.location="sysLogout.php?sysid="+document.getElementById("divSys").value; 
   }
   $(this).data("isopen", !open); });
</script>
```

it isn't work and return value for sysid is fix (1 or 2 for instance) for all option.
why?

Comment: jQuery would be `$("#divSys").val()` as well

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`. This should resolve your issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divSys").mouseup(function() { 
             var open = $(this).data("isopen"); 
             if(open) { 
                 window.location="sysLogout.php?sysid="+document.getElementById("divSys").value; 
             } 
             $(this).data("isopen", !open); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank u very much konstantin. i missed it & ur issue is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divSys").mouseup(function() { 
             var open = $(this).data("isopen"); 
             if(open) { 
                 window.location="sysLogout.php?sysid="+$(this).val(); 
             } 
             $(this).data("isopen", !open); 
        });
    });
</script>
```